# CTRL+ALT+DEL login option gets disabled on every shutdown

Tags: authentication

My issue is the opposite: I WANT to have the CTRL+ALT+DEL requirement on every logon but something keeps resetting my local Security Policy back to 'Enabled', meaning 'disable the logon requirement for CTRL+ALT+DEL.'  I have to reset that option at Secpol every time before I logout so that I can have the CTRL+ALT+DEL on the next reboot.

As well, I made sure the checkbox is checked (it's checked and greyed out) on the 'Advanced' tab at the User Account to have the CTRL+ALT+DEL on.

Also, in the registry, I went to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon and checked to make sure the DisableCAD is set to 0. [To Enable Secure Logon, type 0.] I don't what else I can to do at this point.

I'm on a Win10 box, i7, Win10 64-bit Enterprise LTSC. Is it the OS?
Does anyone have an idea on what I can do for this issue? Think it's malware?

Comment: If you want to get the process that makes the changes try Sysinternals process monitor. When running Procmon for a long time make sure to filter out everything non-relevant (only enable registry monitoring for the specific path you want to monitor) and enable "Drop filtered events".

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was using a program, 'Mouse Without Borders' and that was causing the issue. It kept disabling the Ctrl+alt+del setting. Once deleted, evey thing went back to a normal, secure boot.